# jQuery Mobile: Listview Autodivider Linkbar position: fixed problems on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a page which has a listview autodivider linkbar, which list alphabetical characters and help user to navigate through a listview, here's the code and example:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/listview-autodividers-linkbar/

My problem is, that in mobile devices, the position: fixed does not work, so jQuery implement some tricks in order to make it fixed. Everything works finem but in Chrome it simple doesn't work.

I investigate, and the problem is from the wrapper (ui-panel-content-wrap i think):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

If I put

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: none;
```

The position: fixed in Chrome start working, but the menu panel, anyone, the left or right one stop working, because the transform property to open and close is now disabled.

Any idea how to make both work?
I'm driving MYSELF crazy trying to fix it.

Comment: The problem seems with the fixed linkbar on the right side. It doesn't scroll. If you're using JQM 1.4, you have to wait until the new version is officially released.

Comment: i check jqm 1.4 and it seems that is gonna fix that problems. i guess ill just have to wait. thanks for the tip